# Xades4j verification xades-x and xades-x-l

Tags: xml, verification, xml-signature, xades4j

Is there some pathc or upgrade of xades4j control so I can verify xades -x and xades -x-l with xades4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there's no official support. However, there's a series of patches submitted on the project's issue tracker that add that support. They weren't reviewed nor integrated yet.

Comment: I was wondering: do they work? How about the patches for xades-a?